# Unable to iterate over an array in state in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update my cart using redux but I constantly get this error:

TypeError: state.products is not iterable

my reducer looks like:

```js
/* eslint-disable import/no-anonymous-default-export */
const initialState ={
    products:[]
}
export default (state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "ADD_TO_BASKET":
            return {...state,products:[...state.products,action.payload]};

        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: what `state.products` looks like when you try to add an item?

Comment: It's undefined. Also if I remove ...state.products in return statement it works only one time and only adds the latest item clicked, this time in console it gives undefined for the first time then if again item is added it returns object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is

```
        default:
            return "";
```

You probably want to return `state` as it is instead.

```
        default:
            return state;
```